# Getting error when I create controller views/actions using Entity Framework

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have created an ASP.NET MVC project using Entity Framework. Trying to create a new controller, I am getting an error:

> There was error running selected code generator
>   Exception  has been Thrown  by the target  of an Invocation

I am connecting to the database using an `appsettings.config` file.

I am adding controller like this

[image]

but after finish filled column I am getting error Like this

[image]

But when I create new project in Visual Studio that working fine.

Comment: have you checked the logs in your data context class?

Comment: how can i check  logs in data context class?